# Hadoop namenode container unhealthy

Tags: docker, hadoop, namenode

I am following a guided course on Apache Airflow, I am building images but finding my Hadoop namenode container unhealthy. When checked docker logs I found this:
Re-format filesystem in Storage Directory root= /hadoop/hdfs/name; location= null ? (Y or N)

When I went inside container in directory /hadoop/hdfs/name and appying the command `hdfs namenode -format` 
I chose both options one by one `Y` and `N` but still unhealthy. What can I do

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.